# Are Pervasive Computing and Pervasive Sensing the same.concept?

Tags: terminology

Pervasive Sensing focuses on sensors and Pervasive Computing talks about using sensors for example. Are they both the same thing but different names?

Comment: The field of Pervasive Computing is sometimes also called Ubiquitous Computing, you can see Pervasive Sensing as a subfield.

Answer (score 2):

First off, keep in mind that these are just labels. They don't have a formal definition.

That said, I would say that they tend to imply different things.  Pervasive computing is about embedding sensors and computational systems throughout everyday life -- that includes sensors, computing, actuation, integration with the rest of the world, etc.  To me, pervasive sensing would refer just to the sensing part, without much emphasis on how the sensor data is used.  Thus, I would think of pervasive sensing as a subset of pervasive computing.

But don't take this as authoritative or a formal definition.  These labels are loose, and reflect social shared values as much as anything else.